# My bitmap image is cropped

Tags: android, image, bitmap, httpurlconnection

I'm using this method:

```
public Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage) throws FileNotFoundException {

    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 800;

    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            break;
        }
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
}
```

To decode an URI from mi camera and then send to my webserver via an `HttpURLConnection` object in POST headers. But my instead get my original image:
[image]

I get an cropped imagen:

[image]

I don't know why. Perhaps my `decodeURI` method is wrong? Anybody know other best method to send my image compressed to my webserver?

I used right now the next way insteaf of my `decodeUri` method:

```
mybitMap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
```

and I have the same problem. And when I tried to open the image in my webserver with Photoshop, I see an advertisement wich says "This document may be damaged (the file may be truncated or incomplete). Do you want continue?" And , after continue, I see a black space in the bottom of the image...

Anybody knows why? My code:

```
Bitmap mybitMap = null;
   try {
      mybitMap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   imagen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

And I send this in POST Headers:

```
 Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Post your image width and height before and after scale.

Comment: I dont understand you. :( Mi image width and height is variable (depending of the camera resolution)

Comment: I save an base64 uri scheme of my bitmap form send to my webserver. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: Then why you use a scale?

Comment: `But my image is cropped:`. Please tell what you mean by that. Your image looks nice. We cannot see if your image is cropped of course. You are scaling down your image. Is that what you mean by cropped? If so then do not scale it down.

Comment: `Post your image width and height before and after scale`. Just do that. You are scaling it down. width_tmp and height_tmp.

Comment: `an base64 uri scheme of my bitmap` ??? What is that?

Comment: breakpoint that while loop

Comment: I will update my answer with more code. (I send a base 64 uri to my webserver) Please, let me few minutes

Comment: Now you have posted two pictures. But quite confusing all. Just post the original first and then the cropped one.

Comment: Why are you calling that cropped? The bottom is cut off. The height changed. Not the width.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, What is the proper term?

Comment: I don't know. The point is that you just should tell what's happening. What you see.

Comment: Well I think my images are self explanatory :S